# How to resync bookmarks?

Tags: firefox, sync, bookmarks, firefox-sync

I've already synced my bookmarks in waterfox(64bit version of firefox). I've uninstalled it recently and installed firefox. How to sync back my bookmarks to Mozilla?

Answer (score 2):

Supposing that the synchonization from Waterfox was correct.

from the new Firefox browser installation.

1. Go to Tools, Options, Firefox Account
2. Enter your Mozilla account credentials
3. Open your email, you will have an email from Mozilla, click the link to accept the new device/browser (acceptation can require some minutes)
4. On "Sync Settings", Check "bookmarks"
5. Go to Tools, click on "Sync Now"

[Optional and just for verification and additional information]
 4.1. Click on "Manage devices" you will be redirected to your Mozilla account
 4.2. Click "Show" button for "Devices & Apps", you should see your old sync from Waterfox in the list

In theory "Mozilla sync" stores encrypted data in their "cloud" so your bookmarks should be there.

I always sync my different firefox authenticated browsers,  first the the more recently updated and no much later the outdated browser.

Answer (score 0):

Options > Options > Sync

This implies that you have synced with Firefox Sync earlier.